# Cloning two bitbucket repo into a same folder

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, liferay-6.2

I have two bitbucket repo in which the first repo contains all the Liferay related sdk, the second repo contains only the projects(have four folder such as hooks, portlets, layoutpl, themes).

I took the clone of the first repo which contains the SDK, lets say the folder name is **liferay-sdk**. now on to the same liferay-sdk in need **hooks**, **portlets**, **layoutpl**, **themes** folders which are in repo two.

But now when I tried to pull the repo two contents onto the same **liferay-sdk** folder it is giving me Folder not empty.

I am using Source Tree.

Note: I need commit and push privilege needed only to **hooks**, **portlets**, **layoutpl**, **themes** in source tree and not to the other things in **liferay-sdk**. How can we ignore things expect **hooks**, **portlets**, **layoutpl**, **themes** in **liferay-sdk**

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: You can add two remotes and you can pull from two different remotes.

Comment: @Foolish Thanks for the reply, I did'nt get you, can you show me with some examples

Comment: @Ôrel submodules ?, I did'nt get you

Comment: Seems like your repo `two` needs `liferay-sdk`, so I suggest you to add `liferay-sdk` as a submodule into your repository `two`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now when I tried to pull the repo two contents onto the same `liferay-sdk` folder it is giving me `Folder not empty`.

Yes, you cannot clone a repo using a existing non-empty folder.

You could clone the second repo within the first:

```
cd liferay
git clone /url/second_repo
```

But that would give you:

- a nested git repo (meaning `liferay-sdk` would at minimum record a **[`gitlink`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entry in the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))
- a nested subfolder (meaning hook is not directly under `liferay-sdk`, but rather in `liferay-sdk/second_repo/hooks`)

That would remain true even if you were using submodules.

Instead, you could:

- clone the second repo elsewhere
- make symlink (`ln -s` or `mklink /J` on Windows) for the four folders you want directly under `liferay-sdk` to `second_repo/xxx` (`hooks`, etc).
- add those symlink folder names (like `hooks`) to your `liferay-sdk` `.gitignore` file.

Comment: But can we track the updates for `hooks, portlets, layoutpl, themes` folder if we put those under `.gitignore` file...can you give a more details on that. I don't need to track any updates for likferay-sdk files

Comment: @AlexMan Adding them in your gitignore will make the parent repo ignore them. But the second repo will still continue to track any evolution: you will still be able to add, commit and push from the second repo.

Comment: I am not that expert in git...it would be great helpful if you can specify me the steps with the command i need to do

Comment: @AlexMan Said steps are in the answer: clone the second repo anywhere you want *outside* the first repo and add symlinks (symlinks are not git commands, just a system way of linking folders)

Comment: Is it like this `mklink /J D:\second-repo D:\liferay-sdk`

Comment: @AlexMan on Windows, it is `cd D:\liferay-sdk` and: `mklink /J hooks D:\second_repo\hooks`: that will create a subfolder symlink (junction) `hooks` in `D:\liferay-sdk`, pointing to `D:\second_repo\hooks`